# Polymorphism in Python VS Polymorphism in JAVA

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, oop, polymorphism

I'm trying to understand the polymorphism in python. Gone through lot of article but there is one doubt still there in my mind. When I compare with java it is little bit confusing for me in Python.

As per my knowledge polymorphism is "one thing in many forms". Polymorphism can be demonstrated using operator overloading, and method overloading. Let's take method overloading as a means to demonstrate Polymorphism concept. In java we can write it without use of inheritance. See below code.

```
 public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(add(1,2));;
        System.out.println(add(1,2,3));
    }
    public static int add(int a,int b){
        return a+b;
    }
    public static int add(int a,int b,int c){
        return a+b+c;
    }   
}
```

Python code:

```
class TestPolymorphism:
    def add(self,a,b):
        return (a+b)
    def add(self,a,b,c):
        return (a+b+c)

obj = TestPolymorphism()
print(obj.add(1,2)) #will get an error
print(obj.add(1,2,3))
```

The same method overloading works in java but not in python. Why there is difference?. If I want it to work then I have to change my python code as below:

```
class TestPolymorphism:
    def add(self,a,b,c=None):
        if c ==None:
            sum  = a+b
            return sum
        else:
            sum = a+b+c
            return sum

obj = TestPolymorphism()
print(obj.add(1,2))
print(obj.add(1,2,3))
```

I'm not getting convinced that above the code is an example of Polymorphism. There are article like [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/polymorphism-in-python/) not giving me convincing point.

can anyone give me theory behind the polymorphism in python?

Comment: Your question is about method overloading. To me it has nothing to do with polymorphism (but maybe that concept is not strictly defined).

Comment: why did you think polymorphism is universal defined in every language same way?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science) Polymorphism = interfaces/inheritance in Java, multi-inheritance and duck-typing in Python. What you do is what Wiki called "ad hoc polymorphism", and it's not usually called polymorphism at all - Wikipedia also says "The term "ad hoc" in this context is not intended to be pejorative; it refers simply to the fact that this type of polymorphism is not a fundamental feature of the type system" + "In dynamically typed languages the situation can be more complex[...]"

Comment: @sahasrara62, I got your point.

Comment: @Olivier, please see the article [here] (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/polymorphism-in-java/). Polymophism can be demonstrated in two ways. 1. Method overloading, 2. Operator overloading.

Comment: Well as h4z3 pointed out, method overloading can be considered "ad hoc polymorphism". But honestly that's not what people usually mean by "polymorphism".

Comment: in python you can do both overloadings at same time in a function as it is not strongly typed as java, so stop wasting your time comparing the polymori... in java and python and understand them individually, though the concept remains same

Comment: @sahasrara62, I don't think I'm wasting my time. Trying to learn something. As programmers we have to deal with multiple progrmming languages. I have to do comparison of concepts between the languages.  If you say "concept is same but approach and implementation is different" and many agree that then it is a new learning for me. If go for interviews and if they ask questions like this then I should know some convincing point. Anyhow thanks for your answer.

Comment: @h4z3, I think the wiki is very much informative. Thanks for sharing it.

Comment: @RaviKumarB just focus on DSA , people in Bangalore dont care about language command

Comment: @sahasrara62, yeah sure. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The way I have always understood this:

Polymorphism is a concept that basically says it looks like the same but does things differently, depending on context.

1. if you have a method of the same name which has a different amount of arguments, this is method overloading.
2. if you have a method of the same name with the same amount of arguments, but does a different thing depending on the class, this is method overriding.

Note: I say amount of arguments, as for dynamically typed languages, the type does only matter at run time. For Java, for instance, it is not only the number of arguments, but also the type, of course.

Both are concrete ways to deal with polymorphism.
In detail, depending on the language you are using, the concept might be implemented and sometimes even interpreted differently.

Comment: Are you trying to say " Method overloading and Polymorphism both are different and there is no relation b/w them?"

Comment: No, I think these are different levels, really.
Polymorphism is a concept, and method overloading is a concrete way of a part of polymorphism.
Overriding is another concrete way of dealing with another part of polymorphism, for instance.

Comment: In that case you have to edit your answer right?. point(1) says method overloading and point(2) says polymorphism . But you know both are forms of polymorphism. Point 2 is the definition of Method Overriding isn't it?

Comment: you are correct, I myself was mixing up concept and implementation. I hope now its better understandable.

Answer (score 0):

By what i understand in java even you have the same name of the method, you have different method, while in python when you have:

```
class TestPolymorphism:
def add(self,a,b):
    return (a+b)
def add(self,a,b,c):
    return (a+b+c)
```

the last add that you write override the last ones.

In conclusion, when you have add with different arguments the best option add(self, a,b,c==None, ..., n=None) and if...

Answer (score 0):

Well from my understanding of polymorphism, it means one thing in many forms, and that can be illustrated using user app interface.
A python code could be implemented such that at runtime, a draw method could be used to change the user app interface from drop-down list to textbox. etc.
def draw(controls):
for control in controls:
I hope you get the point.